# How to findViewById() an @android:id/list element in an Android activity?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get the `ListView` by using the `findViewById` function, yet I am unsure what I am trying to find or what to use as an argument: `R.id.list` does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your activity, try getListView(), you'll have access to your ListView

Comment: This is not entirely correct. This is true only for ListActivity.

Answer (score 50):

You can call:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```